# ElasticSearch ignoring field named 'tags' when specified in "fields"

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a search index, `products`, containing a field named `tags`, which is an array. Tags values appears in results when I don't add a `fields` section to my query, but when I do, it's just ignored outright, and doesn't appear in results, as shown below.

```
$ curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/products/_search?pretty' -d '{  "query": {"match_all": {} }, "fields": ["tags", "id", "slug"], "size": 2}'
{
  "took" : 4,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 321826,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "products",
      "_type" : "products",
      "_id" : "39969794",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "fields" : {
        "id" : [ "39969794" ],
        "slug" : [ "slug-39969794" ]
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "products",
      "_type" : "products",
      "_id" : "21296413",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "fields" : {
        "id" : [ "21296413" ],
        "slug" : [ "slug-21296413" ]
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

Is there a reason or known issue for this? Is `tags` some kind of reserved word for ElasticSearch?

I'm using ES version 1.1.2 (Lucene 4.7).

Comment: Can you post the mapping for for the `products` index? And maybe the source for those two docs?

Answer (score 1):

`tags` is not an ES reserved word.  So that's not your problem.

Is your tags an array of atomic types (numbers, strings or booleans)?  Or is it an array of objects?

`fields` only works with leaf nodes.  So `"fields": ["tags"]` should work fine with an array of strings but it would fail with an array of `tag` objects.

Answer (score 0):

Confused as to why you are using "fields" instead of "terms?"

```
$ curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/products/_search?pretty' -d 
 '{"query": 
    {
    "match_all": {} 
    }, 
   "terms": ["tags", "id", "slug"],
   "size": 2}'
```